# Delete the first 2 words and the last 2 words in a string in a dataframe using Regex Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a column in a df contains the following strings:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Sentence':['The cat is jumping off the bridge', 'The dog jumped over the brown fox, the bus is coming now', 'The bus is coming']})
>>> df
                            Sentence
0  The cat is jumping off the bridge
1  The dog jumped over the brown fox, the bus is coming now
2  The bus is coming
```

I would like to use regex to delete the first 2 words and the last 2 words of all the strings. One row can contain multiple strings `(row 1)`. In case the string is less than 4 words, nothing should be returned for that string `(row 2)`. The output should be as below:

```
>>> df
                            Sentence                               String
0  The cat is jumping off the bridge                          is jumping off
1  The dog jumped over the brown fox, the bus is coming now   jumped over the, is  
2  The bus is coming
```

I tried with this code just to see how it works for the first 2 words, but it is not working. Any suggestions would greatly be appreciated.

```
df['String']= df.Sentence.str.join(line.split()[2:])
```

Comment: So, the "string" is any substring between commas or start/end of string?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, the string is a string between commas. "The dog jumped over the brown fox, the bus is coming now" are 2 strings separating by a comma

Comment: What about `df['Sentence'].str.replace(r'(?<![^,])\s*\w+(?:\W+\w+)?\s*|\s*\w+(?:\W+\w+)?\s*(?![^,])', '')` then?

Comment: Please kindly accept the answer that worked for you best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single call to `Series.str.replace` with

```py
df['Sentence'].str.replace(r'(?<![^,])\s*\w+(?:\W+\w+)?\s*|\s*\w+(?:\W+\w+)?\s*(?![^,])', '')
```

See the Pandas demo:

```py
>>> pattern = r'(?<![^,])\s*\w+(?:\W+\w+)?\s*|\s*\w+(?:\W+\w+)?\s*(?![^,])'
>>> df['Sentence'].str.replace(pattern, '')
0        is jumping off
1    jumped over the,is
2
```

**Regex details**

- `(?<![^,])` - a comma or start of string must appear immediately to the left of the current location
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `(?:\W+\w+)?` - an optional occurrence of one or more non-word chars followed with one or more word chars
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `|` - or
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\w+` - a word (one or more word chars)
- `(?:\W+\w+)?` - an optional occurrence of one or more non-word chars followed with one or more word chars
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?![^,])` - end of string, or a location that is immediately followed with a comma.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Sentence':['The cat is jumping off the bridge', 'The dog jumped over the brown fox, the bus is coming now', 'The bus is coming']})

df['try'] = df['Sentence'].apply(lambda s: ', '.join([' '.join(x.split()[2:-2]) for x in s.split(',')]))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                            Sentence                  try
0                  The cat is jumping off the bridge       is jumping off
1  The dog jumped over the brown fox, the bus is ...  jumped over the, is
2                                  The bus is coming
```

Comment: The output for the second string is expected to be `jumped over the, is`

Comment: @Serial Lazer, this method will not work because it understood "The dog jumped over the brown fox, the bus is coming now" as 1 single string while it is 2 strings. So the output should be "jumped over the, is"

Comment: @SerialLazer thank you, for some reason, it didn't work but the code that Wiktor wrote above worked for me

Comment: @tlqn no problem, I just realized I didnt rename the variable to 's'. If u'd like to try again, it should work

Answer (score -1):

Without using regex :

```
string = #your string
string = string.split()
string.pop(0)
string.pop(0)
string.pop(-1)
string.pop(-1)
string = "".join(string)
```

Comment: The output for the second string is expected to be `jumped over the, is`

Comment: to do this he has to strip() with the , and use my code two times

Comment: No idea how you want to use this code in Pandas. If you use it in `.apply`, it will be quite slow since it won't be vectorized.

Comment: i don't use pandas so i made this post a wiki post, plz edit it